# Is there a way to find solution if all variables cancel out?

Tags: linear-algebra

- Factory A produces: 12 Tables and 6 Chairs per hour
- Factory B produces:  8 Tables and 4 Chairs per hour

How hours does EACH factory need to work to produce 48 Tables and 24 Chairs?

The linear equations are:

$$12A+8B=48$$
$$6A+4B=24$$

The first equation is twice the second, so everything cancels out.
But with trial and error, you find 3 solution:

1. A=0 and B=6
2. A=2 and B=3
3. A=4 and B=0

What does it mean when variables cancel out or when all of them are zeroes?

Comment: It means there are infinitely many solutions. But I'm not sure you've read the problem correctly; I think it is asking about each factory separately, not together. (Not sure though, it's a bit ambiguous.)

Comment: I don't think your equations are correct. What is $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I have to agree with @QiaochuYuan: This question is ambiguous. Are you asking how much each factory, individually, needs to run to meet the production target, or are you looking at the total output of both factories. Are they supposed to run for the same amount of time or is this looking for all combinations of production times that will achieve the goal? As well, it the goal to produce *exactly* that number of goods?

Comment: I have to disagree. I think there are two problems here: how long does it take factory A to do its thing and how long does it take factory B to do the same thing?

Comment: If I understand it right one solution is,  that factory $A$ runs 2 hours and factory $B$ runs 3 hours. In this case factory $A$ produces 24 tables and 12 chairs. And factory $B$ produces 24 tables and 12 chairs. Both factories produce 48 chairs and 24 tables.

Comment: @Lubin Well, that’s not at all the problem to OP appears to be trying to solve.

Comment: Must the factories run for a whole number of hours? You haven’t made that explicit in your question, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations are correct. These equations are linear dependent. The first equation is twice of the second equation. That means that you one equation can be dropped. Now you can solve one of the equations for $A$ or $B$. Letßs solve the first equation for B.

$12A+8B=48\qquad |-12A$

$8B=48-12A \qquad|:8$

$B=6-1.5A$

If $A$ and $B$ need not to be integers then the solution is every point on the graph below, where $A,B \geq 0$.

If $A$ and $B$ must be integers then the three points (marked black) are the solutions. This is what you have already found out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You actually won't ever stop finding solutions with trial and error.
The thing is that both equations carry the same information about what values the variables contain. Any solution such that:

$b = 6-(3a/2)$

or

$a = 4-(2b/3)$

is a valid solution.

For you question of how to find these solutions, you can find these equations by solving either of the two equations that you have for one of its variables. Then, you can generate as many solutions as you would like. For example, starting by solving for a variable:

$6a+4b=24$ -> $3a+2b=12$ -> $3a = 12-2b$ -> $a = 4 - 2b/3$

Then I just plug some number into b, for example, 7

$a=4-(2*7)/3$ -> $a = -2/3$

which means that one solution of the infinite amount of solutions, is: $a=-2/3$, and $b=7$

Answer (score 0):

If both factories work together, in 1 hour they produce 20 tables and 10 chairs. Thus, it will require 2 hours and 24 minutes to produce required number of tables and chairs. ($20x=48, x=2.4$ hours, $10x=24, x=2.4$). I agree that the problem is ambiguous.